# how to find non-linear equation parameters using a dataset

Tags: interpolation, regression, nonlinear-functions

I got a dataset of 2 variable X and Y. I think these 2 variables are link by an equation as follow:

Y(X) = a ( b + c * X^d)^e      ,

I have a lot of observation Xi and Yi and I would like:
      1) Define parameters c, d and e.
      2) confirm my approach is correct

In a first step, I tried using the solver from Excel but results are not too bad but I would like a more robust approach if it is possible.

Thank you in advance very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct format should be:

```
Y(X) = a [ b + (c * X^d)]^e
```

A nice calculator is [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Y%28X%29%20=%20a%20%5B%20b%20%2b%20%28c%20%2a%20X%5Ed%29%5D%5Ee), very detailed.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see how calculating the derivative would help me.